# Allowing multiple users to start a PostgreSQL server

Tags: postgresql, server

I am new to postgres, I have set up some software that requires it as a backend and am trying to allow other members of my team the ability to spin everything up. When another team member attempts to start the server with `pg_ctl`, they get the following error.

```
FATAL:  data directory "/path/to/my/db/" has wrong ownership
HINT:  The server must be started by the user that owns the data directory.
```

I understand that I can `chown` the dir to that person, I believe that there can only be one 'owner' of a dir at a time.

How can I set it up so that a group or a list of users can start the server?

Comment: I'm not sure. But as far as I remember the ownership on directories is always set to user, not the group (only x for group), so you need either to be owner, or member of sudo I believe

Answer (score 0):

Leave it running. There's no reason to stop and start it.

If for some reason you really need to do that (why?!), use `sudo`. You can create an `/etc/sudoers` that lets people `sudo` only as certain users to run certain commands. So for example you might *only* let them `sudo -u postgres pg_ctl -D /path/to/my/db ...` and nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

There is a reason why it is called "database management system". If you need different people to do maintenance operations on your system, use sudo and provide them with the ability to stop/start PostgreSQL. You can even limit sudo to certain commands.

Please don't try to change ownership of database directories, unless you know exactly what you are doing.